# How do I create togglable tabs with images in the tab header part?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs, toggle

I am trying to create a togglable area with images in the tab header section. So if I click on the first image in the header, it would show some content. If I click on the next image in the row, it should toggle to the next content and so on. Any idea how should I start it?

I had a look on bootstrap tabs but not sure how can I use it for my own problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Have a look at this:**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1"><img src="http://www.downloadsbyvita.com/images/video.jpg"/></a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h3>HOME</h3>
    <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working fidddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/ttpxoxob/1/

Comment: Hey @Raviteja! Thanks for the quick response. Yes, that's what I meant. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Cant understand exactly what your problem is because we dont have your code but below thing can help you.

```js
$('.imgContent').hide();

$('.dataToggle').click(function() {

  $('.imgContent').hide();
  $("#" + $(this).data("img")).show();
});
```

```css
li {
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.content {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="dataToggle" data-img="one">img 1</li>
  <li class="dataToggle" data-img="two">img 2</li>
  <li class="dataToggle" data-img="three">img 3</li>
</ul>
<div class="content">
  <div id="one" class="imgContent" style="display:block;">img one content</div>
  <div id="two" class="imgContent" style="display:none;">img two content</div>
  <div id="three" class="imgContent" style="display:none;">img three content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey imGaurav! Thanks for the quick reply. What you suggested is not exactly what I am looking for, probably it is because as you mentioned my description wasn't too clear. Sorry about that. But someone else just answered below my question.